# Multiple touch in list view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a List of inkwell in my app this inkwells each pushes a new page.if i press two of those items in my app it opens two new page. i want to avoid this.
i want to disable onTap in my inkwells for sometime.
how can i achieve that.

```
ListView.builder(
                          itemCount:
                              controller.supplierRequestDetails.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                            return InkWell(
                               onTap:(){
                                 Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'hello_page'); 
                  }
                        )
                          });
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on "disable for sometime"?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Do you want to disable some inkwell widgets in your listview.builder? I don't understand how did you press two inkwells at once.

Comment: @UsamaKarim i dont want the onTap on my inkwell work for 1 sec

Comment: @VihangaRandunu yes. consider user uses two fingers to touch items in list

Comment: @Ardeshirojan oh in that case I don't think you got a solution. If you believe a user may tap on two items at once, you can prevent this by improving your app's UX. For example, you can increase the space between list items.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your Inkwell with IgnorePointer

In your case, if you are using any state management method you can ignore setState and use relatable.

```
bool isClicked = false;  //Default false


IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: isClicked,
  child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        isClicked = true;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), () {
          isClicked = false;
          setState(() {});
        });
        print("CLICKED 123123123");
        setState(() {});
      },
      child: Container(height :150, width: 150,color: Colors.amber)
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not worked

Comment: where do you write the isClicked var? inside the list itemBuilder or outside? @Ardeshirojan

Comment: i tested both but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

Handle onTap like below:

```
   bool isTap=false;

    ListView.builder(
              itemCount: controller.supplierRequestDetails.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                return InkWell(onTap: () async{
                    if(!isTap){
                        isTap = true;
                        
                        await Navigator. pushNamed(context,'hello_page');
                        
                        isTap = false;
                      }
                    },
                 );
   )
```

Comment: this did not worked.
as i see your edit i think you did not understood me correctly. im not gonna touch one item two times. two items are gonna touched one time

Comment: are you passing any child to InkWell?

Comment: yes for sure i just forgotted to add on example

Comment: check my edited ans.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `AbsorbPointer` or you can just add `condition`

```
AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: true, // by default is true
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: (){
          print('pending to implement onPressed function');
        },
        child: Text("Button Click!!!"),
      ),
    ),
```

or you can easily manage with `conditions`

```
     ListView.builder(
                              itemCount:
                                  controller.supplierRequestDetails.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                return InkWell(
                                   onTap:(){
                                  if(yourConditon == true){
                                     Navigator.pushNamed(context,'hello_page'); 
                               }
                              }
                             )
                            });
```

Answer (score -1):

You Need to add child in inkwell to be clickable

```
    ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount:
                                      controller.supplierRequestDetails.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                                    return InkWell(
   /**-----> */    child:Text("$index"),
                                       onTap:(){
                                         Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'hello_page'); 
                          }
                                )
                                  });
```